# How do I compare the value of an Enum with all possible values of the Enum in an Enum method and avoid missing return statement?

Tags: java, enums

I'm just learning about enumerations in Java. When I run the code below I get an error which I also reproduce below. Basically, my question is: when I define a method in an Enum, and in that method I want to check the value of the enum so that I can do something based on that value, how do I perform this check?
Below I have an Enum with three possible values, and in the method `getNext`, I have three if statements comparing the value of this Enum with each of the three possible values. But I still get an error saying that there is a path without a return.

```
package enumerations;

enum TrafficLightColor2 {
    RED(12), GREEN(10), YELLOW(2);

    private int waitTime;

    TrafficLightColor2(int waitTime) {
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }

    int getWaitTime() {
        return waitTime;
    }

    TrafficLightColor2 getNext() {
        if (this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.GREEN)) {
            return TrafficLightColor2.YELLOW;
        }
        if (this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.YELLOW)) {
            return TrafficLightColor2.RED;
        }
        if (this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.RED)) {
            return TrafficLightColor2.GREEN;
        }
    }
}

// A computerized traffic light.
class TrafficLightSimulator2 implements Runnable {
    private Thread thrd; // holds the thread that runs the simulation
    private TrafficLightColor2 tlc; // holds the traffic light color
    boolean stop = false; // set to true to stop the simulation
    boolean changed = false; // true when the light has changed

    TrafficLightSimulator2(TrafficLightColor2 init) {
        tlc = init;
        thrd = new Thread(this);
        thrd.start();
    }

    TrafficLightSimulator2() {
        tlc = TrafficLightColor2.RED;
        thrd = new Thread(this);
        thrd.start();
    }

    // Start up the light.
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(tlc.getWaitTime());
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }
            changeColor();
        }
    }

    // Change color.
    synchronized void changeColor() {
        tlc = tlc.getNext();
        changed = true;
        notify(); // signal that the light has changed
    }

    // Wait until a light change occurs.
    synchronized void waitForChange() {
        try {
            while (!changed)
                wait(); // wait for light to change
            changed = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }

    // Return current color.
    synchronized TrafficLightColor2 getColor() {
        return tlc;
    }

    // Stop the traffic light.
    synchronized void cancel() {
        stop = true;
    }
}


class TrafficLightDemo2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TrafficLightSimulator tl =
                new TrafficLightSimulator(TrafficLightColor.GREEN);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.println(tl.getColor());
            tl.waitForChange();
        }

        tl.cancel();
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
$ javac enumerations/TrafficLightDemo2.java
enumerations/TrafficLightDemo2.java:26: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error
```

Comment: Your `if` statements could fail, and there's no `return` available in that case. After your `Red` condition, return `this` or a default state

Comment: Also, within your enum, you don't need to have TrafficLightColor2 on your states (i.e. `this.equals(GREEN)` instead of `this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.GREEN)`)

Comment: I get that logic of the error message, but don't the if statements cover all possible cases? The method getNext() is inside of an enumeration, and the enumeration can only be one of the three enumeration constants, each of which is tested in an if. In theory am I missing some way that all the ifs would fail?

Comment: You might be overestimating what `if` statements can do, they execute either their block of code, or they don't, regardless of what class or object structure they might be in. A safer bet would be to set an initial `returnValue` to some default, have your `if` statements assign to `returnValue` then return at the end of that method.

Comment: You're right in that Enums have limited ranges/values, but code wise it is not feasible because all non-void methods need to return something in every and all situations, even if logic says that should never happen. "In theory" should only apply if your code is also "sound", in this case what you're seeing is expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
TrafficLightColor2 getNext() {
    if (this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.GREEN)) {
        return TrafficLightColor2.YELLOW;
    }
    if (this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.YELLOW)) {
        return TrafficLightColor2.RED;
    }
    if (this.equals(TrafficLightColor2.RED)) {
        return TrafficLightColor2.GREEN;
    }
}
```

This method doesn't return the value if all 3 `if` are false.

Add return at the and or better throw an error, e.g.

`throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported enum")`

Comment: yes, the error is clear. However, I am inside of an enumeration instance method. The enumeration can only have one of three values, and I tested for each one of the possible three values in getNext(). Why isn't the compiler able to realize that if the enumeration exists (which it does since I am inside of its method), then it will necessarily fall into one of the three if cases?

Comment: You declared that your method must return TrafficLightColor2, defining the Exception in default case you clarify that you aware that all cases are covered. Compiler is not that smart to understand that you've covered each and every case. It's a static analysis that says that there are uncovered flows.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using instance fields in enum classes is that you can associate implementation details easily with your constants that are independent from your API.  In other words, you can easily associate data with your enum constants that would admit an elegant solution that you aren't forever married to in the case that, for example, you need to add a new enum constant.

So, you can greatly simplify your implementation while fulfilling the same contract as follows:

```
enum TrafficLightColor2 {
    RED(2, 12), 
    GREEN(0, 10), 
    YELLOW(1, 2);


    private int order;   // implementation detail; non-exported
    private int waitTime;

    TrafficLightColor2(int ord, int waitTime) {
        this.order = ord;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }

    int getWaitTime() {
        return waitTime;
    }

    TrafficLightColor2 getNext() {
        final int nextColor = (this.order + 1) % 3;  // magic numbers introduce fragility
        return Arrays.stream(TrafficLight2.values())
                .filter(e -> e.order == nextColor)
                .findAny()
                .get();
    }
}
```

This version has some advantages to your original implementation:  it is easier to maintain since, if enum constants are added, the compiler will force you to add an order value.  In the original, if you forgot to modify your if-else-block after adding a constant, your program would continue to work but it would not provide the correct behavior.  And because the implementation of the `order` is hidden, you are free to remove it or change it to some other implementation at any time without affecting the correctness of your API.

Comment: Yes, that is a nice version. However, what I really want to know is why the error existed in the first place given that I accounted for all possible enumeration constants in my if statements. Isn't a return statement after all three if statements going to be non-reachable code in practice? Or is it not unreachable code?

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough to know that you've tested all possible conditions in your if statements.  It assumes that the final if statement could evaluate to false.  In the case that it did, execution in the method would reach the final bracket without encountering a return statement (which is required).  You could repair your method as it stands by throwing an exception before the final bracket.  This is customarily `throw new AssertionError("Unreachable");`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered including the next state along with the declared values?

```
public enum TrafficLightColor2 {
    RED(12, "GREEN"), GREEN(10, "YELLOW"), YELLOW(2, "RED");

    int waitTime;
    String nextState;
    Configurations(int waitTime, String nextState) {
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        this.nextState = nextState;
    }
    public int getWaitTime() {
        return waitTime;
    }
    public String getNextState() {
        return nextState;
    }
}
```

With this you can get the next state as

```
TrafficLightColor2 trafficLightColor = TrafficLightColor2.GREEN;
System.out.println(TrafficLightColor2.valueOf(trafficLightColor.getNextState()));
```